# Error: File path too long on windows, keep below 240 characters

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

So, I made some changes to my build.gradle(app) file and android studio gives me this error (open the image in new tab for better viewing):
[image: Error description from Logcat]

My build.gradle(app) file (this is not the edited file, I deleted new lines of code and still no luck/solution.):
[image: Build.gradle]

Everything was quite working well until I made some changes in the build.gradle(app) file, but then I deleted those new lines of code and android studio is still keep giving me the error.
The error relates to the **compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'**.
I have tried deleting/renaming those png images inside the stated folder,but then when I rebuild the project, the png images are automatically downloaded.
My build.gradle(project) file contains **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'**. I want to know what causes this error, and how to fix it? Many thanks.

Comment: gradle works with **relative paths** and compiles the long project-paths. android-studio-2.2 works with **absolute paths**. Is there a way to tell android-studio-2.2 to work with relative paths?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. I don't know a fix for your exact problem, but I found a work around; I see your project has a deep file path hierarchy. Why not just move your project up from a lower level?

Ex: `C:\Projects\YourProject`

That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: There is some other solutions but i consider moving the project closer to the root directory as the best practice because it is easier to maintain simpler file hierarchy.

Comment: In my opinion, using a separate short build path allows for easier sharing of the project with others. It would fix the problem regardless of where other team members store their project files. In companies with strict file hierarchy rules, it can help if they happen to use bloated paths with a lengthy depth or overly long naming schemes. However, short build paths wouldn't fix anything if your own naming schemes use overly long package/file names. If that's the case you should certainly shorten the root project path. At the end of the day though do what works best for you. Just my $0.025

Comment: Sometimes you have no change to adjust the file hierachy because you unpack some archives in your project, etc.

Then if you want to clean up the unpacked archive how could you delete it with gradle? For my project it does not work under Windows.

Comment: Addition to my comment above: I created a Java class with this single method:
    public static void cleanDir(File dir) {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    cleanDir(f);
                }
                f.delete();
            }
        }
    }
Then in my build.gradle task I call this method with a file reference of the directory to delete. This directory path may be deeper than 240 characters, the limit of Windows.

Answer (score 172):

You could also try changing your build directory for your project since that is where most of the path issues will arise. In your root build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    repositories {
       ...
    }
}
```

Android Studio will pick up on the change and still show your new build location in the Project view. It's a lot easier than moving your entire project.

*EDIT*

While Windows 10 Insider Preview now offers the ability for allowing for longer file path limits these limits currently are only actually accessible to apps which have specifically enabled support for longer file paths.

At the current time, it appears that these applications with the extended path enabled seem to be only apps that are installed via the Windows Store.

At the current time, Gradle does not and potentially cannot have this option enabled to utilize the enhanced NTFS file path length.

Comment: Best solution  of all !!! Worked for me. Only changes the build directory, no need to move the entire project.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, works great and has no impact on the project itself.

Comment: Genius! I had the same problem happen out of the blue after updating my gradle.  (Google play services uses ridiculously long file/folder names.) This solution is simple, and since the build files are generated, it shouldn't be in anyones source control. So this answer should generally be an easy workaround for the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I better choose this solution as it will impact only the build folder

Comment: Just encountered this error when updating buildToolsVersion to latest (24.0.2). Suddenly couldn't build project, and this is much easier than moving project files (that may break my mojo!)

Comment: this was the best solution. I just need to update build location than project location.

Comment: @lodlock could you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533932/android-studio-failed-to-crunch-file-change-build-gradle-to-solve-it-err ?

Comment: Fantastic! Easy to implement and works perfectly. Thanks a million for sharing!

Comment: This error was fixed in Windows 10 (see [here](https://mspoweruser.com/ntfs-260-character-windows-10/)), but still occurs with gradle. Is there a way to fix this error without changing the build dir in Windows 10 and later?

Comment: What if the path of the content of the build dir is still too long? How could you delete it with gradle?

Comment: not working for me i am building ndk-built command and this solution also not working for me . any other solution please im stuck in ndk build

Answer (score 12):

**Cause of problem :** 'C:\users...\commom_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png' icon path length is greater than 240 character which exceeds **Maximum File Path Length Limitation** of Windows OS.

**Solution is :** Move your project into top directory like 'C:\your_project' or reduce length of your project name.

Here is windows path limit chart 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

As a very solid alternative to actually moving the project I'd suggest using a hard link. The syntax of that would be like this

```
mklink /J C:\AndroidProjects\ProjectName C:\MyVeryVeryVeryVery…VeryVeryVeryLongPath\ProjectName
```

Now you can work on your project in C:\AndroidProjects\ProjectName, and have the changes right where your project is supposed to be.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea, but now get a javascript out of heap memory error. Sad, because this is exactly the fix I would suggest!

Answer (score 2):

As an addition on lodock's answer, you can use a hash on the project path if you have lots of projects with the same name:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

def hashString(String s){
    MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1").digest(s.bytes).encodeHex().toString()
}

allprojects {
    buildDir = "C:/AB/${hashString(projectDir.getAbsolutePath())}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortening project paths is really a bit of a hack, Ivan Neeson's response seems the way forward.

If you are lucky enough to be using Android Studio then you will see a useful error message about file length.
If however you hit the same issue doing a command line ionic build all you will see if some kind of crunch error for a png file and it's not so obvious.

The real issue is Google Play Services having such extravagant filenames such as common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png which is simply not Windows friendly. Dump that inside an Android build and the path explodes outside our control to platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png

Answer (score 1):

You Should Have To Keep Your Project Directory As Less Deep As Possible
For Example:-
D:/AndroidWorkSpace/ProjectName

Because Gradle Support Only 240 Character length of Project Path

Thanks

Comment: Gradle is the problem, not Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue when I have two repeated folder in same like,

```
E:\project-one\project-one
```

and when it has a large length of folder name like,

```
E:\project-one-with-very-big-name
```

To avoid this problem make a folder of project simple and short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NTFS junction point to create shorter path to your project.
To read more about Junctions read this :
[Hard Links and Junctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A junction (also called a soft link) differs from a hard link in that the storage objects it references are separate directories, and a junction can link directories located on different local volumes on the same computer. Otherwise, junctions operate identically to hard links

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users:

You might be tempted to create a network share to the project root folder and then map to it.  This technique will shorten the overall path length but will cause problems for Android Studio due to the difficulty in detecting modified files.  A better solution is to use the windows **subst** command.  Here is an example script to circumvent the problem.   Tweak names as necessary and modify to point to your project and install directories.

File: launchAS.cmd

```
subst P: "C:\private\java42\ide\42g\workspaces\AndroidStudioProjects"
cd "C:\private\java42\programs\android-studio-base\bin"
start studio64.exe
```

The above commands will create a P: drive and map it to the project root folder.  This will reduce the overall path length to project files and might give you some relief for the too long path name problem.  Use P:\ as you would have used the long root name when opening projects.

To remove the mapping use command:  **subst P: /d**

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , my project is in C drive and it is in deeper path location, What i did I just moved my project to other lower deep path location and it works, you just change the project location and project should not be in deep location hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different experience with this problem. First I has this error but then i noticed that my previous projects in the same directory were opening. This is the path:

C:\Users\koralis\Documents\extraction\Ex_Files_Android_App_Dev_LDS_Upd\Exercise Files\Ch01\01_06\ImageAssets

Surprisingly, I updated that gradle version to 
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' from  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

This solved my problem.