# Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a terrible time trying to find out whats wrong with this problem. When I trying to click a button in my app i get the following error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error
>   inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer

Here are my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.anders.ugym"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TodoActivity" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And my activity_register.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_messages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/username" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/password_label" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_up"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:onClick="register"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_label" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signInButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:onClick="showLogin"
        android:text="@string/already_have_an_account_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.anders.ugym/com.example.anders.ugym.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:368)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
                                                                           at com.example.anders.ugym.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:368) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
                                                                           at com.example.anders.ugym.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
                                                                           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:747)
                                                                           at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:115)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:111)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:107)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:60)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3605) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3677) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:368) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
                                                                           at com.example.anders.ugym.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: The Exception usually tells you what's wrong (missing attribute/wrong attribute value. Can you have a closer look and post it here?

Comment: Added the exception message :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567982/activitypreferencefragment-error-inflating-class-com-android-internal-widget) by **[Neel0507](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039732/neel0507)**:

> I had the same error, and here is how I dealt with it. In the
>   styles.xml file, in the first "AppTheme" style put Base infront of
>   Theme.AppCompat. So it would be
>   "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar".
>
> After this, go to your "AndroidManifest" and in your activity do not
>   use "AppBarOverlay". So it would be just
>   "android:theme="@style/AppTheme".
>
> Furthermore, in "AndroidManifest" remove "package name" from your
>   activity name, and just use ".SettingsActivity".
>
> If you have other activities then instead of defining AppTheme in each
>   activity, just use android:parentActivityName=".SettingsActivity."
>
> I know you want to have an action bar and removing AppBarOverlay could
>   help. Let me know if it works.

Hopes it's helps..