# My BLE GATT service application keep crashing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am new app builder for android. i am trying out a tutorial for BLE GATT service app. it is supposed to detect BLE devices and show appropriate GATT services. i followed the tutorial properly and adjusted other necessary stuffs like location permission. however my app keep crashing. it is not even starting.

I am following this tutorial:
https://github.com/jeffddrake/ble-android-gatt-server/tree/master/BluetoothLeGattSample/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.appgatt">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <activity android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"/>
        <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my DeviceScanActivity classfile:

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 7500;

    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 255;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        if (!mScanning) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                    R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_scan:
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                break;
            case R.id.menu_stop:
                scanLeDevice(false);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
        if (device == null) return;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
        if (mScanning) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {

            verifyPermissionAndScan();

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private void verifyPermissionAndScan() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.location_already_given, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != LOCATION_REQUEST) return;

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_allowed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.permission_not_allowed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my logcat:

```
2019-07-23 13:57:20.604 24213-24213/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-07-23 13:57:20.605 24213-24213/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-07-23 13:57:20.606 24213-24213/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c50,c270,c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.appgatt 
2019-07-23 13:57:20.609 24213-24213/? I/example.appgat: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-07-23 13:57:20.647 24213-24220/? E/example.appgat: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
2019-07-23 13:57:20.676 24213-24213/? D/ConnectivityManager_URSP: Ursp sIsUrsp=false, sIsCheckUrsp=false, uid=13634
2019-07-23 13:57:20.678 24213-24213/? D/Proxy: urspP is null: 13634
2019-07-23 13:57:20.775 24213-24213/? W/example.appgat: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-07-23 13:57:20.777 24213-24213/? I/chatty: uid=13634(com.example.appgatt) identical 8 lines
2019-07-23 13:57:20.777 24213-24213/? W/example.appgat: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-07-23 13:57:20.777 24213-24213/? W/example.appgat: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-07-23 13:57:20.777 24213-24213/? W/example.appgat: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-07-23 13:57:20.791 24213-24213/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-07-23 13:57:20.820 24213-24237/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
2019-07-23 13:57:20.837 24213-24213/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-07-23 13:57:20.841 24213-24213/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appgatt, PID: 24213
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appgatt/com.example.appgatt.DeviceScanActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6990)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2494)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2812)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2120)
        at android.app.Activity.initWindowDecorActionBar(Activity.java:2834)
        at android.app.Activity.getActionBar(Activity.java:2776)
        at com.example.appgatt.DeviceScanActivity.onCreate(DeviceScanActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7326)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6990)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010433 a=1}
2019-07-23 13:57:20.842 24213-24213/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5459)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:660)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:87)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:82)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:73)
            ... 32 more
```

Rest are same as the tutorial so i am not adding here. i have not added any custom layout resource file as shown in the tutorial and instead used default theme.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923798/error-inflating-class-com-android-internal-widget-actionbarcontainer?noredirect=1&lq=1, check this link

Comment: Thanks for replying. i have already checked the thread. it is actually opposite of what they said. you need to add the package name for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is solved. the problem was in manifest file. just added the package name in front of the activity name.