# No resource found error in android

Tags: android

I got code from my friend its working fine in his system and also my other system but when i run in my system its giving me error . can anyone please help me what is the error.

```
AAPT err(1063464211): C:\Users\Nitesh\Downloads\\PT.MultiRestaurant15-Env43-Tsachi&NiteshBaseline-NEW\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-plus\8.4.0\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_plusone_small_off_client.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1063464211): C:\Users\Nitesh\Downloads\PT.MultiRestaurant15-Env43-Tsachi&NiteshBaseline-NEW\PT.MultiRestaurant15-Env43-Tsachi&NiteshBaseline-NEW\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\drawable-xhdpi\abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
AAPT err(1063464211): C:\Users\Nitesh\Downloads\NEW\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\8.4.0\res\drawable-hdpi\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/powered_by_google_light').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_pressed_holo_light').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_off_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/cast_ic_notification_0').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/cast_ic_notification_1').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/cast_ic_notification_2').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/cast_ic_notification_1').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_disabled').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_pressed').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_normal').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_on_0_mono_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_on_1_mono_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_on_2_mono_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_on_1_mono_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_on_mono_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_off_mono_dark').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/ic_media_route_disabled_mono_dark').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Nitesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '****'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.25.10.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
}
```

Its working fine on other system but i dont know why its giving error in my system. can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me ,thank you all the people who commented with the help of you am able to get the solution.StakeOverflow rocks :)

```
buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You should accept your answer if it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to standalone sdk manager and update and then:

buidltoolversion:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

and dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

Comment: ok and i updated my class path also is that good . dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }

Comment: after that i got this error C:\Users\Nitesh\Downloads\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\drawable-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task **app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\drawable-hdpi\abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png: Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters :

Comment: Check this for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905687/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters

Comment: You are my hero this is worked for me buildDir = "C:/tmp/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}" . thank you for your time . i really appreciate  it .