# File path too long on Windows

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing this issue.i google it but find the solution moving the project to short path but i want to know why android cannot handle this.

> Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters :
>   E:\ccavenue\Seamless\Integration Source Code\ccavenue-mobile(OTP-Auto
>   Read
>   Kit)\TestOTPAppNew\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.3.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png

Comment: The error message says it already: keep below 240 characters

Comment: gradle works with **relative paths** and compiles the long project-paths. android-studio-2.2 works with **absolute paths**. Is there a way to tell android-studio-2.2 to work with relative paths?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905687/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters

Answer (score 2):

A far more simpler way to resolve this issue rather than moving/ creating multiple copies of your application folder:

1. Create a shortcut of your application folder "TestOTPAppNew"
2. Move the shortcut to an outside shorter path like C:\Documents\TestOTPAppNew_Shortcut
3. Put this entry in your main build.gradle

   ```
   allprojects {
   **buildDir = "C:\\Documents\\TestOTPAppNew_Shortcut\\${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"**
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }}
   ```

Rebuild and you are all set!!

Answer (score 1):

Your Error Says that
In windows the file path length cannot be longer than 240 characters, so this error message simply means that you've reached the limit. For example:

**C:\programs\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\folder5 etc..**

Try to move it somewhere else, like

**E:\Projects\Project1**

and if even that is too long try just extracting it in E:\ directly.