# Failed to crunch file or path too long with play-services 9.0.0 or newer

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Android Studio: 2.2 Beta
gradle: 2.2.0-beta1

When I update the app:gradle.build file for the current play-services library - 9.4.0, I get a "failed to crunch file" error for 3 files.  Changing this back to 8.3.0, the error goes away.

This issue applies to play-services 9.0.0 or newer

for:
Android Studio: 2.2 preview 3
gradle: 2.1.0

I get a similar issue: "File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters" for 3 files.

I think both errors are related to the library's folder structure.  I could relocate the project however, I'm not sure if this is a simple move the folder of something more complicated.  I also feel that I should not have to reconfigure my folder structure to accommodate this.

Comment: to get rid of error "path too long with play-services 9.0.0 or newer", try to shorten the path hierarchy of your project file. For example on Windows, put in your C: Drive. Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905687/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters) for more info.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905687/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters