# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file PNG file

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to compile my program that uses Google Play Services and I am getting this error. The *.png file in question comes from the Google Play Services Package so I cannot change it.

How to fix this?

> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file `my_app_folder`\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-tvdpi-v4\common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
>
> into
>
> `my_app_folder`\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-tvdpi-v4\common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
>
> Error : com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file E:\Viral_Patel\viral\Android_studio_demo\android-page-transition-master\android-page-transition\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png into E:\Viral_Patel\viral\Android_studio_demo\android-page-transition-master\android-page-transition\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png

Comment: Error: File path too long on windows, keep below 240 characters
Just try to use shorter path for your project. In my case i just moved my project source from current folder to desktop and after opening project from desktop this problem solved automatically.

Comment: That's probably the correct answer @LuckyRana

Comment: I got same problem, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34680168/5253418

Answer (score 1):

Change the image's file name.
common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9

it gives you this error because whether the file name is too long or invalid, like if it has a dot on it.

so, change common_plus_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9 to signin_light_f