# Android Studio Android Wear error

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

hello im try to make a app for android wear i get this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':pokemondamagecalulatorwear:mergeDebugResources'.
>    Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\pokemondamagecalulatorwear\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.0.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png into C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\pokemondamagecalulatorwear\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
>   Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\pokemondamagecalulatorwear\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.0.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png into C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\pokemondamagecalulatorwear\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Android Wear *per se*. It's apparently a file path length limitation: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39621978/252080