# Firebase Connectivity Error

Tags: android, gradle, firebase

I am trying to connect my Android app to Firebase. I have done everything right so far other than the fact that when I put the libraries under my dependencies and sync, I get an error message that reads.

> 'Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to
>   crunch file
>   C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\androidfp3_examples\androidfp3_examples\KonnectionsKonnect\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.0.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
>   into
>   C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\androidfp3_examples\androidfp3_examples\KonnectionsKonnect\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png'

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905687/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution... Android Studio only allows the path to be so long, that being said, just move the file to the desktop or a top level file, and viola!!!