# Android Studio 3.0 failed mergeDebugResources - error: file not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat, android-studio-3.0

I created an empty project and added `appcompat-v7-26.1.0` support. I'm getting many errors like that:

> C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\e0aabf040e64856c88683f1511ddf095\res\layout\tooltip.xml: error: file not found.

which lead to:

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> > Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
> >     details

I can solve it [by adding property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988102/errorcom-android-tools-aapt2-aapt2exception-aapt2-error-check-logs-for-detail) in `gradle.properties` file

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

... but this is rather workaround than fixing the cause. If you take a look at this missing file path it seems quite long so I was wondering if the path length may be the problem as posted for other issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905687/error-file-path-too-long-on-windows-keep-below-240-characters). Unfortunately I don't know how can I changed it as most of the length is inside the `gradle` directory, so even if I change `GRADLE_USER_HOME` path (`C:\Users\username\.gradle` in my case) it's not a big profit. 
I also tried to set

```
android.enableBuildCache=true # false didn't work as well
android.buildCacheDir =c:\\temp\\
```

but with no luck. I'd appreciate a helping hand or any tip in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I changed In build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'
}
```

issure here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36972228

Comment: It helped however I used version `2.3.0`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue.
Changing gradle runtime from Gradle 4.4.1 to Gradle 4.1 helped.
(no changes in dependencies, if you use Jenkins make sure that environment variables updated correctly `gradle --version`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is gradle is looking in `C:\Users\username.gradle\caches` for the cached appcompat libraries. I'm assuming that username.gradle doesn't exist? Or is that a typo?

In any case, I had a similar issue, and specifying the gradle user home directory fixed it. In my case, gradle was looking inside `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`, and not finding the cache because it didn't exist.

I set an environment variable for GRADLE_USER_HOME so that gradle would cache things in a set location. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489991/aapt2-error-appcompat-v7-files-not-found-in-mergedebugresources/50490266#50490266) question for a little more detail.